# ¿Cómo mover el scroll a una sección en particular?

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo una página sencilla que muestra mis películas y series favoritas directamente en la cabecera, tirando de una api. Ahora mismo, lo que hago es mostrar 5 elementos y, cuando el usuario pulse "mostrar más", se suman otros cinco más y aparecen opciones para pasar de página, si las hay.
Entonces, me gustaría hacer que, cuando se pulse a mostrar más o a siguiente, el scroll o la vista se vayan al inicio de la sección. Como se cargan elementos nuevos, queda un poco feo que el usuario tenga que ir manualmente hacia arriba.
Investigando, he probado lo siguiente:

```
const scrollTop = (section) => {
    window.scroll({
        top: section.getBoundingClientRect().top,
        behavior: 'smooth'
    });   
}
```

`section` es la constante que pille en cada caso con `querySelector()`. El caso es que me mueve el scroll y parece funcionar con la primera sección situada en la página. Pero no funciona con las siguientes; es decir, me envía al inicio. He probado, además de con `.top`, con `.y`
¿Alguien tiene una idea de cómo hacer esto?

Comment: si las section todas tienen el mismo id te va a encontrar siempre la primera, `console.log(section)` antes del scroll te puede dar una pista de si es siempre la misma

Comment: Al primer section ponele un id particular, y el query selector hacelo a ese #id-particular

Comment: @AgustinG. se me había olvidado comentarlo: sí, cada sección tiene su propio id y uso distinta constantes para cada llamada a la función, dependiendo de si está actuando sobre una sección u otra